# SOX and fade in and fade out

Tags: sox, libsox

I'm trying to create a fade in and fade out for several wave files that I won't know the total time duration in seconds of.  I read the manual but the example I see all looks like I need to know the full length of the file.
Can someone post an example of fading in 5 seconds and fading out 7 seconds without knowing the full length of the wav file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a simple bash script, as this:

```
#! /bin/bash

WAV_IN=$1
WAV_OUT=$2

FADE_IN_L="0:5"
FADE_OUT_L="0:7"

LENGTH=`soxi -d $WAV_IN`

sox $WAV_IN $WAV_OUT fade $FADE_IN_L $LENGTH $FADE_OUT_L
```

`soxi -d` returns the length of the wav file. See sox [documentation](http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxi.html) for more on soxi.

You can run this bash script as follows:

```
./fadeWav test.wav faded.wav
```

Answer (score 9):

From the sox manpage:

> fade [type] fade-in-length [stop-position(=) [fade-out-length]]
>
> ...
>
> If  the  audio length  can  be  determined from the input file header
>   and any previous effects, then -0 (or, for historical reasons, 0) may
>   be specified for stop-position to indicate the usual case of a
>   fade-out that ends at the end of the input audio stream.

So to fade in 5 seconds, and fade out 7 seconds:

```
sox input.waw output.waw fade 5 -0 7
```